# connectionString with MYSQL runtime windowsform

Tags: mysql, windows, winforms, entity

I want to change the connectionstring  from windowsform with Entity 4.0 
 I want to change the userID, Servername, Database, Port on forms.
 The database is MYSQL
 My App work together MSql and Entity

Im able to change the form connection from MySQL in runtime because it change the register on windows but  the entity I dont no how can I do this.
How can I do this.

I tried several examples but not work.

For Exemple:     public void SaveConexaoEntity()

```
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var connectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        connectionString.ConnectionStrings["cartorioEntities"].ConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=" + txtServidor.Text + ";" + "User Id=" + txtUserId.Text + ";" + "password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";" + "Persist Security Info=True;database=" + txtBaseDados.Text + ";" + "port=" + txtPorta.Text + "&quot;" + " providerName=System.Data.EntityClient";
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

I´m using Windows form with C# I need to create a Frontend in form to change the parameters  server, userid,port , database in runtime.
My entity connection is running together Mysqlconection.

```
<add name="cartorioEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=10.0.0.2;User Id=root;password=m@m813;Persist Security Info=True;database=cartorio;port=3306&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Are There others ways to do this.

When I run it it says no understand the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give examples of what you've tried there's nothing much to say. However, there is a really good site, [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com), with a [MySQL](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) page.

You'll need to know what drivers you are using - with the EF Framework, it'll be one of the .NET ones.